# Product catalog datasets

Tags: data-request, products

I'd love to get a large product catalog dataset, preferably with pictures. Doesn't really matter what kind of products, so long as it's reasonably clean, the products have some attributes (length, weight, price, category, etc.) and I can make a decent demo out of it. Amazon's or Overstock.com's catalogs would be ideal. Books, movies, consumer goods, anything that a normal person would understand.

Can anyone suggest sources for such data?

Comment: thanks, this data set is util for me study. Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- BestBuy publishes product data through [Products API](https://bbyopen.com/documentation/products-api/) or in RDF/XML dumps (see [sitemap here](http://stores.bestbuy.com/sitemap.xml)).
- [Linked Open Commerce](http://linkedopencommerce.com/) is an attempt to aggregate data from e-shops, including descriptions of products.
- An older (2009) attempt to publish product data is [ProductDB](http://productdb.org/).

Answer (score 5):

Following [this](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/562/does-there-exist-a-global-database-of-all-products-with-ean-13-barcodes) discussion, the [product open database](http://www.product-open-data.com/) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: link is not working.

Answer (score 4):

[Semantics3](https://www.semantics3.com/) has an API for products.  It gives you UPC, dimensions of products, pricing and other details that typically show up on an Amazon search.

Semantics3 is not open data, but there is a [free tier](https://www.semantics3.com/pricing) that allows 1000 API calls per day, which may be enough for experimentating.

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of routes that you could take depending on the scope and requirements of your project. I recommend using Amazon's product affiliate API, however there are a few other options available as well.

**Paid**
If you want an accurate and comprehensive database of products that can be looked up by UPC or EAN, you can use GS1 US. This organization is responsible for distributing and maintaining UPC and EAN codes for products in the US. While this information is very accurate, this data is **NOT** free and requires a subscription.

https://www.gs1us.org/tools/gs1-company-database-gepir

**Free with Terms & Conditions**
Amazon offers a comprehensive database of product information. This API is available through their affiliate program. The information supplied via this API contains much of the information you're looking for such as weight, price, and category. While this information does not cost money, be sure to read through their terms of service.

https://affiliate-program.amazon.com

**Quick**
A final solution involves scraping content off product database providers over the web. There are a number of online databases that may provide more information than the options above. Products can be programmatically retrieved by UPC or EAN using the examples below. Again, be careful not to break any terms of service with these approaches as well.

[https://www.upccodesearch.com/upc/$UPC](https://www.upccodesearch.com)
[https://www.barcodespider.com/$UPC](https://www.barcodespider.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Your question was asked a long time ago but you can check [www.katalog.world](http://www.katalog.world)
It's a tool to collect product information from GTIN (EAN or UPC)
Hope it will be usefull for you or other.