# Open Product Data sources and importing into SQL

Tags: tool-request, sql, okfn

I'm trying to import the .sql file from [Open Product Data](http://www.product-open-data.com/download/), the POD Database Dump. The site recommends to use BigDump, but when I try to run the php script from BigDump in my localhost, I'm getting this message:

> Stopped at the line 339.
>
> At this place the current query includes more than 300 dump lines. 
>   That can happen if your dump file was created by some tool which
>   doesn't place a semicolon followed by a linebreak at the end of each
>   query, or if your dump contains extended inserts or very long
>   procedure definitions. Please read the BigDump usage notes for more
>   infos. Ask for our support services in order to handle dump files
>   containing extended inserts.

How can I fix this? I already tried to open the .sql file, but it always stops working/crashs in my Mac

Are there other sources for product data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your first question, Open Product Data provides [guidelines](http://www.outpan.com) for data importing which suggests using software such as BigDump to handle importing the data.

Now, to answer your second question:
[Outpan](http://www.outpan.com) is my personal project focusing specifically on creating a free database of all barcoded products. The database currently includes more than 18 million products and an [API to easily access the content programmatically](http://www.outpan.com/developers.php). As I mentioned before in [another answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/562/does-there-exist-a-global-database-of-all-products-with-ean-13-barcodes/1554#1554) our top priority is to keep this completely free (hopefully even open source) and accessible for everyone.

**NOTE: I am affiliated with Outpan.**

Comment: is there an api from where we can search by product name or by brand name ?

Comment: @yunas not at the moment, but this is something we may add in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

If you know where the end of each query is, then you can add the semi-colon with a command line parsing tool like 'sed'. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) for details about 'sed' on Mac OSX.

You can read about how to use 'sed' to add a semicolon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202555/adding-semicolon-at-the-end-those-do-not-have-one). To know the exact command, I'd have to know the file details. If each query is on one line, then it's quite straightforward. If each query is multi-line, then you have to program some logic to check if it is the end of a query (i.e. having two new lines, or something).