# Names of popular products found in retail stores

Tags: data-request, products

Where can I get names of physical products found in retail stores, like:

`"Coca-Cola Zero"`, `"LEVIS 501 ORIGINAL FIT JEANS"`, etc...

I know there are a lot of products in the world, so it can be limited to a single country, or limited to major brands, or limited to wide-circulation products only, but the less limited the better.

Translations should be considered as the same product, for instance `بلاي ستيشن 4` is the exact same product as `Playstation 4`.

Comment: There are a *lot* of products in the world.  Can you explain what you're trying to do with this data, as it might help people give a useful answer.  (eg, if you're using it for commerce, see http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/562/263 )

Answer (score 2):

[Open Product Data](http://www.product-open-data.com/) (an [Open Knowledge](https://okfn.org/) project) has a lot of this kind of data: http://www.product-open-data.com/download/

In my experience, the data quality varies but is improving.

Comment: Whoops! I just saw Patrick's comment above.