# Free UPC database?

Tags: barcodes

I'm working with a food bank/soup kitchen and I'd like to be able to scan in donated food cans, packages, and other items. A short trip around the Google block seemed to offer UPC data of two sorts: good (but you must pay a lot) and bad (free). Is there in fact any sort of free UPC database that is accurate and fairly complete? We don't have any budget for the pricey services.

Comment: @JoeGermuska : not a 100% duplicate ... as there might be something food-focused that would be a better solution than the ones given.  (although the other ones would be an excellent place to start)

Comment: EAN 13 and UPC are not the same.

Comment: @147pm it's my understanding that the only difference is that EAN13 makes the country code for US/Canada (0) explicit. And the answers on that post seem like exactly what anyone would give for this one, including several UPC-centric answers like http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/3911/18

Comment: If you're still looking (and @147pm's excellent answer hasn't helped), email me at opendata@barrycarter.info and I might be able to help, provided you don't need to distribute the data outside your organization, and that you're looking primarily for food products. See also http://www.directionsforme.org/

Comment: This answer I think covers your question http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/3911/1511