# Clothing Dataset

Tags: data-request

I just want to play with a clothing related dataset. I didn't find any free one. I see that a company called Semantics3 offers something related to that for a certain price.

The database I'm looking for would have information about the size, retailer, price, color, maybe a unique barcode, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will struggle with a free service. Have a look at [this thread](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/562/is-there-a-global-database-of-all-products-with-ean-13-barcodes), which the consensus is that either the information is incomplete, inaccurate or both.

My expectation is you will have to apply to a paid service, or purchase the data directly from the clothing supplier.