# Is there any open data-set for products per brand (with description)?

Tags: data-request, products

I am looking for a dataset/API where I can query a product brand and it can give all the products of that brand along with their description.

Comment: You might start by googling for UPC databases, since the first few digits (I forget how many) of a UPC identify the company. Of course, brand is a little finer grained, but this may be a start.

Comment: relevant? or duplicate? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/734/1511

Comment: What do you mean by brand? What's an example of the type of data you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can try our [product database at Datafiniti](https://datafiniti.co/products/product-data/).  The entire data set is not "open source", but you can run searches and get up to 1000 records per month for free.

Answer (score 0):

For computer related products check out https://icecat.biz/

Datasets / API / Product sheets and images.

It looks like there are a lot of other product categories added also.