# APIs / Services that can link product names to their UPC/SKU codes

Tags: api, products

I have an ever growing database of products that users on my site are entering themselves. The input form for users to submit their products (as part of a troubleshooter forum) is very quick to encourage forum posts so when products are defined just a type, brand and model name are requested.

The result is that I have a large database of products which are not connected to official manufacturers UPC / SKU codes. I want to improve my site by using APIs that retrieve images for products, obtain pricing etc but these all request such codes.

So before I can go ahead with that plan I clearly need to find a way to try and improve the quality of my data. Does anyone know of a way to update this old data through some kind of service that can product match based on strings names?

Comment: Various answers here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/562/1511