# How to collect open data from certain branches?

Tags: research, business

When someone wants to build a database of for example all the groceries in the world or all the pharmacies in the world, how can you get this data.
Of course, someone would offer a database for a lot of money but is there something with Google business or anything like that where you can collect the data yourself?

Comment: This is somethng like https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/562/is-there-a-global-database-of-all-products-with-ean-13-barcodes

Comment: openstreetmap.org might be a starting point