# How can we get EAN 13 barcode information of products?

Tags: data-request, products, barcodes

I want to get data for barcode, from EAN. In my case, it's mostly about Funko Pop.

Few example code with "*Good Answer*" as link: [889698466844](https://www.barcodelookup.com/889698466844), [889698327169](https://www.barcodelookup.com/889698327169), [889698471947](https://www.barcodelookup.com/889698471947), [889698247016](https://www.barcodelookup.com/889698247016), [889698256551](https://www.barcodelookup.com/889698256551)

I found [this](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/562/32184) post which have lot of answer, but no one is working fine.

All proposed options:

- [OpenProductData](http://product.okfn.org/) : No longer available. All "reborn" way are not updated.
- [DataKick](https://www.datakick.org/) is no longer working, and [GtinSearch](https://gtinsearch.org/) (the replication) isn't updated
- [OpenFoodFacts](https://openfoodfacts.org/) is only for Food, which is not what I'm looking for.
- [EAN search](http://www.ean-search.org/), [UPC](http://www.upcdatabase.com/), [Barcoo](http://www.barcoo.com/) are not open data
- [Amazon Affiliate](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/) is not open data and require multiple things to use it
- [DukTen](http://www.dukten.com/) : the domain name is for sale
- [Barcode Monster](https://barcode.monster/) don't find content, scrape and take lot of time to run
- [EAN13](http://www.ean13.info/) is in Russian and not open

How can I get barcode information, for free, thanks to open data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with this is that there is, in general, no incentive to make this information available to entities outside the business using the barcodes.

### Why [GS1](https://www.gs1.org/) does not have the information?

They are similar to Internet Number Registries. They only lease the IP addresses to ISP's and Businesses. In the case of GS1, they only lease sections of the various barcode number ranges.

### Businesses that use barcodes manage their database of barcodes.

Working inside retail environments, I've witnessed manufacturers make a number of mistakes:

- Put an incorrect image for the barcode on a product. This requires relabeling the products before retail sales.
- Use another GS1 subscribers number range either by accident or to avoid paying yearly fees to GS1. This requires retailers to accommodate the fact two products have the same barcode, but are different items.
- UPC-E is an 8 digit barcode that represents a 12 digit barcode, frequently used on soda cans and smaller objects. Those numbers can clash with GTIN-8 barcodes, and you can not be determine which code the 8 digit number represents.
- Barcodes can also be used for weighed items, just as fresh cut meat from the grocery. When they wrap you mean and print a label. That label encodes the weight and price, not that it is ham.
- Coupons and sales are also barcodes and often reused by removing the old coupon and entering the new one in the system.
- All proposed options attempt to collect barcodes from the internet or users and match with any information they can obtain about the item. This is often difficult to do without introducing errors.

### What information is available on these barcodes?

- 889698466844
  Looking up this code in [GS1's database](https://www.gs1us.org/tools/gs1-company-database-gepir), we find Funko LLC owns the UPC range starting with 889698 and the EAN block 0889698. The remaining digits 46684 are for their internal use. Typically these are just incremented as needed and have no structure to them. The final digit (4) is a checksum of the other digits.
  Their address on file is: 1202 SHUKSAN WAY EVERETT, WA 98203-7105 US
- Funko also owns this, as it is also starts with 889698 and has a product identifier of 32716 and a check digit of 9.
- Your last three have product identifiers of 47194, 24701, and 25655 respectively. All owned by Funko, LLC.

Comment: I understand. But, I prefer partial data than check it than search myself. Do you have a way to try to get some informations, even if it's not fully right ?

Comment: I put an example on the question, but I will write some others